# Set calculated field to calculate specific records in Access

Tags: ms-access, calculated-field

I have a steering documents query, that has effective date and next revision date, I set the next revision date field to be calculated as after 2 years from the effective date: 
Next Revision Date: DateAdd("yyyy",2,[Effective Date])
However, some of these steering documents don't have a next revision date, only effective date, so I want these steering documents that start with WI to have null value on the next revision date, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

That could be something like:

```
Next Revision Date: IIf(Left([DocumentName],2)="WI",Null,DateAdd("yyyy",2,[Effective Date]))
```